# makeStyle does not work with custom component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make a simple navbar using material ui with a few buttons and a custom drop down menu component. When I try to style it using the makeStyle hook, the styling only applies to the material ui's buttons and heading but not the custom drop down component.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import DropDown from "./DropDown";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { AlgoContext } from "../AlgoContext";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  item: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(5),
  },
}));

const MainHeader = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [algo, setAlgo] = useContext(AlgoContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar elevation={0} position='static'>
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant='h6' className={classes.item}>
            Pathfinding Visualiser
          </Typography>
          <Button variant='contained' className={classes.item}>
            Visualise {algo.type}
          </Button>
          <DropDown className={classes.item}></DropDown>
          <Button variant='contained' className={classes.item}>
            Clear walls
          </Button>
          <Button variant='contained' className={classes.item}>
            Clear path
          </Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainHeader;
```

Comment: Show us the code of DropDown component. This might be because you are passing the prop className to DropDown, but you never use it on container in the DropDown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`className` is a default attribute of React element. You can not style your custom component by passing style object via `className`. Instead of that, you should pass it as a prop to `DropDown` component. Try this:

```js
const MainHeader = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [algo, setAlgo] = useContext(AlgoContext);
  return (
     <DropDown itemStyle={classes.item}></DropDown>
  );
};

export default MainHeader;

const DropDown = (props) => {
  ...
  return (
    <div className={props.itemStyle}>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: In this case it works perfectly with className as atribute too, and just pass className={props.className} , i'm pretty sure he didn't passed the prop and your answer is correct.